# Ubuntu Server 15.10 VirtualBox Bridged and NAT don't work together

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 15.10

I have installed and Ubuntu Server 15.10 as a VM and set up 2 network adapters - the default NAT + a Bridged on to connect to the VM.

lspci among other thing brings

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have added the second adapter like this (this is what I do Debians using eth0/eth1 and it always works fine):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

# Host-only network
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.56.105
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.56.1
```

Each time I change this file I reboot the machine (not sure how to apply the configuration otherwise). So now I can SSH into the machine, but it has no internet connection. When I remove the config for `enp0s3`, internet works again.

Please advise how to make them work together.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446183/how-to-set-up-nat-and-host-only-networking-with-static-ip-address-in-virtualbox) worked for me.

So what I had to do is remove the `gateway 192.168.56.1` line.